# sed wildcard not behaving as expected

Tags: sed, replace, wildcard

trying replace "/data/kollman/appion/*/relion/micrographs" with "micrographs"

```
sed -i 's/\/data\/kollman\/appion\/.*\/relion\/micrographs/micrographs/g' micrographs_all_gctf.star
```

Each line needs two corrections.

```
/data/kollman/appion/17nov14d/relion/micrographs/00001_nonDW.mrc /data/kollman/appion/17nov14d/relion/micrographs/00001_nonDW.ctf:mrc 18326.289062 19408.296875    74.539665   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.032973     3.656274
/data/kollman/appion/17nov14d/relion/micrographs/00002_nonDW.mrc /data/kollman/appion/17nov14d/relion/micrographs/00002_nonDW.ctf:mrc 19867.357422 20695.939453    48.760956   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.034282     3.727132
```

needs to be turned into this:

```
micrographs/00001_nonDW.mrc micrographs/00001_nonDW.ctf:mrc 18326.289062 19408.296875    74.539665   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.032973     3.656274
micrographs/00002_nonDW.mrc micrographs/00002_nonDW.ctf:mrc 19867.357422 20695.939453    48.760956   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.034282     3.727132
```

but instead, the result I'm getting is this:

```
micrographs/00001_nonDW.ctf:mrc 18326.289062 19408.296875    74.539665   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.032973     3.656274
micrographs/00002_nonDW.ctf:mrc 19867.357422 20695.939453    48.760956   120.000000     2.120000     0.200000 87500.000000    14.000000    -0.034282     3.727132
```

The problem seems to be the way I'm using wildcard here.  I need to have it because that part of the folder structure is always going to be different since this command is intended to be generalizable to all folder structures like that.  The asterisk is for the date, which always changes.

Anyways, the wild card replaces the date as expected, but it looks like it is extending all the way past the date and crosses over to the second instance that needs replacement.  The result is that it deletes one entry of the file structure on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard `.*` is matching all characters up to the second instance of `/relion/micrographs`.  You need a more deterministic pattern.

Also, use a different sed expression delimiter so that you don't need to escape each `/`:

```
sed -E 's#/data/kollman/appion/[^ ]+/relion/micrographs#micrographs#g' file
```

- the character class `[^ ]` makes sure that we only match the non space characters and prevent the greedy match that could swallow all characters up to the second instance of `/relion/micrographs`.